# Swift iOS build error, file not found

Tags: ios, swift, build

I have the following error during build.Does anyone know the cause of this?

[image]

Comment: have you tried cleaning the project and deleting the derived data folder?

Comment: Yes i have tried these also.. I think that the text in red (/Users/pmdevios/Documents/repositories/ProductMeIOS/DerivedData/ProductMeIOS/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Product) must be "/Users/pmdevios/Documents/repositories/ProductMeIOS/DerivedData/ProductMeIOS/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Product Me.app/Frameworks" but i don't know where to edit for fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try a clean build. 
Do the following: 
1. In xcode go to `Product` 
2. While holding `alt` click on `clean build folder`

#### OR

`alt + shift + cmd + k`

After clean build try run again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all as 8HP8 said, try to make a Clean Build with `cmd + shift + k` and try to build it again, if it doesn't try deleting the `Derived Data` folder following this steps:

Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Derived Data

Delete **all** data that contains that folder, close Xcode and open it again and then build with `cmd + b`